# Is it possible to store a function and its arguments in a variable?

Tags: python, function

I have seen lots of information on storing functions in variables for execution, but the functions shown are always of the:

```
def foo():
  print("Hello")
x = foo
x()
```

variety. Is it possible to store a function and its variables for later execution? I've currently worked around this by creating a tuple with the function as the first item and the variables as a nested tuple for the second item and then calling:

```
menu_input[KEY_D] = action_system.drop_item, (character,))
...LATER IN CODE...
for key in current_input:
  if key in menu.menu_input.keys():
    func, args = menu.menu_input[keys]
    func(*args)
```

but I would really prefer to be able to store the function and its variables all together.

I would prefer to be able to store:

```
menu_input[KEY_D] = action_system.drop_item(character)
...LATER IN CODE...
for key in current_input:
  if key in menu.menu_input.keys():
    menu.menu_input[keys]()
```

because the function that handles menu input does not understand or care about the menu function itself, so it really doesn't need to see the input or care about the arguments passed.

Is this possible? If so, what am I missing? Sorry if this is obvious or obviously a bad idea--relatively new to python. If it is a terrible idea, I'd love to know why. I'm avoiding making this a class function of the menu item because I'm trying to work within an entity-component-system model where components store all data and the systems operate on them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) function is made for this purppose:

```
from functools import partial
menu_input[KEY_D] = partial(action_system.drop_item, character)
...
for key in current_input:
    if key in menu.menu_input:
        menu.menu_input[key]()
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you! I'll mark as answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Note, `partial` cannot handle all general cases, in particular, you can only partially apply positional arguments in order, e.g consider `def f(a,b,c)`, you have to use something like `lambda a: f(a, 42, 'foo')` to partially apply `b` and `c` instead of `a`, and `b`

Answer (score 4):

You could choose to use a lambda expression with no arguments.

```
def foo(value):
  print(value)
x = lambda : foo("Hello")
x()
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked also. I already accepted the first answer, but this seems to work just as well. I haven't used lambdas before, and none of the examples I had seen showed them being used in quite this way. Interesting!

Comment: @BrentonH this is not a good place to use `lambda` stylistically. `lambda`'s only advantage is to provide an *anonymous function*. If you are going to name it, don't use a lambda. That is actually explicitly a part of PEP8 guidelines. The above is equivalent to `def x(): return foo("Hello")`

Comment: If he is storing the resulting functions in an array/dict, then would you not need an anonymous function?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I THINK I agree with TheManWithNoPlan here but I'm not totally sure I understand what you're warning against. I'm storing these functions so that they can be swapped in and out of a dict. So, the menu system receives input "u", but the menu system doesn't know if it's passing that input to an inventory menu or a pause menu, etc. (The menus are entities with rules attached to them via components; they aren't classed.) I would not actually be using it the exact same way as in TMWNP's sample code above.

Do that makes sense or should I still avoid lambdas here? If so, why?

Comment: For the record, I think using partial is likely better here, but I do not think it is a stylistic problem to use lambdas. One key distinction is that using a lambda expression like this will not evaluate the arguments until you call the function, while partial will immediately evaluate the arguments and store them. It sounds like you want the latter, but it depends on the application.